# MySQL Query Execution Time in a Windows Server 2008 R2 is larger than in standard Windows 8.1 or WIndows 10 OS

Tags: php, mysql, windows-server-2008-r2

When I Executing a same  mysql query, execution Time in Windows Server 2008 R2 is significantly larger than in standard Windows 8.1 or WIndows 10 OS. My Program uses Apache Server 1.8.2 and MySQL 5.1 and PHP 5.3.

Answer (score 1):

it is common problem on windows 2008 server,
you have to check energy saving settings.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2207548

open control panel, energy saving settings, and set to High performance

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I changed the energy saving settings.